# How to handle AngularJS hash bounce in Google Anlaytics?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript

Google Analytics append string is stripped off due to angular hash (`#`) bounce.

when you click on it this link `sub.f.org/fff/sign-up/plan`, the following actions occurs:

1. a link appears in browser as `sub.f.org/fff/sign-up/plan`
2. the link changes immediately to add `#`:  `sub.f.org/#/fff/sign-up/plan`
3. the link returns to original state `sub.f.org/fff/sign-up/plan`

This action is almost like a redirect, which is why the GA append string is stripped.

I am using angular 1.3 and ngRoute angular module for routing (inherting code from developer worked before me, I am no expert on angular) and using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` which causes the `#` to hide.

This breaks google analytics. I do not wish to use other available ngAnalytics or other modules. I wish to have solution within the angular environment.